# Call to plugin method using .proxy()

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use the .proxy() method in a jquery plugin. Not sure what's going on but it's not calling methods.strobe. I've got the following sample code:

```
(function($) {
    var settings = {
    }


    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            alert('init fired');
            $.proxy(methods.strobe,this);
            return this;

        },
        destroy: function() {
        },
        strobe: function(){
            alert('strobe fired');
        },
        show: function() {},
        hide: function() {},
        refresh: function() {}
    };

      $.fn.notify = function(method) {
          if (methods[method]) {
              return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
          } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
              return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
          } else {
              $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.notify');
          }
      };
 })(jQuery);

$().notify();
```

I've got this jsfiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/CZqFW/

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jQuery proxy()` returns a function that closes the first parameter with the context from the second.

You can call the returned function and it will execute immediately.

```
$.proxy(methods.strobe,this)();
```

The only thing this provides to you is replacement of the `this` context for `methods.strobe()`. You can use javascript's `call()` function to accomplish the same thing:

```
methods.strobe.call(this);
```

Your jQuery plug-in has set up `strobe()` as a method on $.fn.notify. So you can call it like this too:

```
this.notify('strobe');
```

Comment: Awesome Mike, perhaps I should have looked closer at the examples in the docs! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$.proxy(methods.strobe,this);
```

returns a new function that calls the `strobe` method but always bound to `this`. It does not actually call the `scrobe` function. So, what you need to do is actually call that function:

```
var strobe = $.proxy(methods.strobe,this);
strobe();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input toby, I had to accept Mikes answer as he beat you to the punch. Thank you both for a definitive answer :)